# Finding a list of un-compilable packages

Tags: sql, oracle

If I make a lot of modifications to tables in Oracle. Is there a way to have a list of packages that don't compile anymore?

I can easely get the list of packages from the list of tables that I changed, but I wonder if it's possible to get everything that isn't compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how you can do that

```
    select 'alter '||decode(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE',object_type)||
       ' '||object_name||' compile '||decode(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','body;',';')
  from user_objects
where status = 'INVALID'
```

Comment: +1 But iff you just want to re-compile everything that's invalid you're probably better off using `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(<schema_name>, false)`.